# Integral inequalities

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Why is it that:

$$\int_{a}^{\infty} xf(x) dx \ \geq \int_{a}^{\infty} af(x) dx$$

Are there any conditions on $f(x)$ for this to be true, like it must be a continuous non-negative function or that $a$ must belong to $\mathbb{R_{>0}}$

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $\,\int_{a}^{\infty} \underbrace{(x-a)}_{\ge 0}f(x) dx \ \geq 0\,$, so $\,f(x) \ge 0\,$ is indeed a sufficient condition.

Comment: Non-negative is a sufficient condition, but not neccessary.  Continuity is not necessary, although the integrals must exist.  $a$ can be any real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that both integrals exists, then $\int\limits_{a}^{\infty} xf(x)\,dx\geq \int\limits_{a}^{\infty} af(x)\,dx \Leftrightarrow \int\limits_{a}^{\infty} (x-a)f(x)\,dx\geq 0$
 note that $(x-a)\geq 0$ so if $f(x)\geq 0$ the result holds. But there may be other functions besides that type, for example take a=1
$f(x)=\begin{cases} -1\; \text{ if } 1\leq x\leq 2\\
100 \;\text{ if } 2\leq x\leq 4\\
0\; \text{ if }4\leq x\leq \infty
\end{cases}$